# HTML - Script - hide the "/index.html" file when going to domain.com/example

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, redirect

for example: On appples website when going to apple.com/support I will come to apple.com/support/ and it should be to apple.com/support/index.html but the index.html is not shown.

i want this on my site: www.jonathangurebo.se for example when going to jonathangurebo.se/contact i will come to jonathangurebo.se/contact/index.html and i dont want to show the index.html.

How should i solve this?

maybe add some line to my .htaccess file? because when going to jonathangurebo.se/mlkhgljfehgljfebgfgb it will come to my error 404 page and show the same link in my adress bar. and not the real link in this case jonathangurebo.se/error/404.html

Comment: Why would it redirect from /contact to /contact/index.html? It shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: You don't want it to show, don't include it in the URL. `DirectoryIndex` will load the default file: `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` from left to right, for example, as long as the request has a trailing slash. Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason your website displays the `index.html` part is because you added it to your HTML page. Rather than making like like so:

```
<a href="http://www.jonathangurebo.se/apps/index.html">Apps</a>
```

You should make links like:

```
<a href="http://www.jonathangurebo.se/apps/">Apps</a>
```

And everything will work just like you expected! :)

Answer (score 0):

the index.html or also index.php is mostly the default file where every browser "looks first" link to www.jonathangurebo.se/contact/ and it will open automatically www.jonathangurebo.se/contact/index.html without showing "index.html" in the browser

just try http://www.jonathangurebo.se/contact/

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, you need to add stuff to your .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Apache's default configuration already does that, so unless he changed something in the `.htaccess` to redirect from / to /index.html nothing needs to be done.

Comment: @AlfredXing Interesting. What Apache doc describes the default configuration?

Comment: @faa See [DirectoryIndexRedirect Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindexredirect) under `Default`

Comment: Thanks @Olaf. As you can see in my comment in the general comments section above, that's pretty clear for me. My comment here has nothing to do with that, is about the Apache documentation where the directives **in this answer** are described as the **default** ones for the mod_rewrite module or the .htaccess file, as stated by Alfred King is his comment here.

Comment: To me, "default" also means the settings that come 'out of the box'. If you install Apache and go to the server root (or any other directory), you don't get redirected to the /index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

From [`DirectoryIndexRedirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindexredirect)

> By default, the DirectoryIndex is selected and returned transparently to the client.

If you have set this directive somewhere, you must remove it. Or if you're allowed to override it in your .htaccess, use

```
DirectoryIndexRedirect off
```